# Redis server responding intermittently to Python client

Tags: python, rest, web-applications, redis

Using Redis with our Python WSGI application, we are noticing that at certain intervals, Redis stops responding to requests.  After some time, however, we are able to fetch the values stored in it again.

After seeing this situation and checking the status of the Redis service, it is still online.

If it is of any help, we are using the `redis` Python package and using `StrictRedis` as a connection class, with a default `ConnectionPool`.  Any ideas on this will be greatly appreciated.  If there is more information which will help better diagnose the problem, let me know and I'll update ASAP.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More data about your redis setup and the size of the data set would be useful. That said I would venture to guess your Eedis server is configured to persist data to disk (the default). If so you could be seeing your Redis node getting a bit overwhelmed whenit forks off a copy of itself to save the data set to disk.

If this is the case and you do need to persist to disk then I would recommend a second instance be stood up and configured to be a shave to the first one and persist to disk. The master you would then configure to not persist to disk. In this configuration you should see the writable node be fully responsive at all times.  You could even go so far as to setup a Non-persisting slave for read-only access.

But without more details on your configuration, resources, and usage it is merely an educated guess.